# FTP Server on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, ftp, home-server

I have a FTP Server on my Macbbok Pro, but when I try to make new accounts for my friends, they can't login. I do how it says, I make an account in contacts, then I add it in System Prefences in the Sharing Section. How can I solve this?

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

Well, first, making a contact in Address Book has no relationship to the FTP server.  The address book is a database that Applications can share, but you'll notice there is no password field, etc, in the address book.  It's intended for human use only.

What version of Mac OS X are you running (10.5 or 10.6?)

How did you set up their account in System preferences -> Accounts?

Is it a Sharing only account?  (Please ensure that it is not an Administrator account)

### What does the FTP log show?  (Utilities --> console --> All Messages & filter using FTPD)

Well, you should see a login for each user:

10/10/09 7:31:45 AM com.apple.ftpd[97113]   launchproxy[97113]: /usr/libexec/ftpd: Connection from: 127.0.0.1 on port: 49341
10/10/09 7:31:45 AM ftpd[97114] connection from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1
10/10/09 7:31:49 AM ftpd[97114] FTP LOGIN FROM 127.0.0.1 as catherine (class: real, type: REAL)
10/10/09 7:33:01 AM ftpd[97114] Data traffic: 0 bytes in 0 files
10/10/09 7:33:01 AM ftpd[97114] Total traffic: 1319 bytes in 1 transfer

Where are your friends?  Are they connecting from the internet?

Do you have your computer's firewall active?  Or if your friends are connecting through a different network (ie internet) does your router have firewall rules setup to allow port forwarding?

http://portforward.com/   Can walk you through setting up forwarding rules for your router...

Comment: Well first of all I am running on 10.6, and I set up my friend's account by clicking the "+" symbol on the right margin where all the accounts are. 
And all the accounts are sharing. I can log in with my own computer account which shows all my files when I login. It should only show the Sharing Files

This is what it says in the console:
10/10/09 9:46:50 AM com.apple.ftpd[213] launchproxy[213]: /usr/libexec/ftpd: Connection from: 172.16.0.8 on port: 49179

Answer (score 1):

- Are you on the same network?
- Are your friends trying to connect to your server from a remote location via the internet?
- Do you have the OS X firewall enabled?
- Do you have a hardware firewall such as a router?

You may need to forward specific ports for FTP to work. Normally FTP uses TCP port 21, but your configuration may differ.

Answer (score 0):

Use pureftpd instead of Apple's ftpd.

http://jeanmatthieu.free.fr/pureftpd/index.html